# Why is overloading == done in global scope in Swift?

Tags: swift

I´m learning Swift and I´m a bit perplexed about why overloading is done at the global scope. This code:

```
class Foo: Equatable {
    var name = "Untitled"
}
func == (lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}

let value1 = Foo()
var value2 = Foo()
let firstCheck = value1 == value2
```

Feels really strange coming from a Ruby background where we declare a `==` method on the object we are comparing:

```
class Foo
  def == (otherFoo)
   self.name == otherFoo.name
  end
end
```

What happens if I declare several classes in the same file? Or does swift look at the types of the lhs. and rhs. to see where to apply the overload?

Comment: Swift example adapted from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Equatable.html

Comment: It seems clear to me that operators are defined in the global scope because not all operators will logically belong more to one operand's type, than the other. In these cases, you can define the operators in a separate file, to emphasize the lack of ownership.

Comment: @Jessy are you talking about doing a apples to pears comparison where the lhs and rhs are different types or when overriding operators for types which may not belong to you?

Comment: Apples to pears doesn't make sense for ==, and I'm not certain that there will ever be a good use case for == on two different concrete types in Swift; it probably makes more sense to define == generically with a protocol they both adopt. Belonging to a module/person/codebase isn't relevant; I'm talking about ownership in the sense that classes, structs, and enums own their members. For example, when you define a multiplication operator for vectors and matrices, the operator doesn't belong more to one type or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because *all* operators are in global scope (and if you like to define your own you need to [declare it first](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-XID_84); see also [the NSHipster article on operators](http://nshipster.com/swift-operators/)). An operator is special because it has a *priority* and an *association*, something normal methods do not have.

Now you could make them part of the objects like Ruby chose to implement, with implicit rules somewhere. The Swift designers chose to make (custom) operators global functions that can be overloaded. I don't know their reasons but I guess it makes things easier and more consistent for the compiler (after all, Ruby is *interpreted* while Swift is *compiled* and wants to do as many optimizations on compile time as possible).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of the *reason*, but all operator declarations are done at global scope. And you're right -- the Swift compiler looks at the types (or the generic constraints, really, in most cases), and use them to determine which function to call. There are a ton of `==` definitions -- you can [see them all here](http://swifter.natecook.com/operator/eqeq/).

Comment: Awesome tool and thanks for the answer, @DarkDust does provide a bit more detail though.